# React Hooks: Trying to access state before unmount returns initial state

Tags: reactjs

In general i'm trying to save global state updates when my component unmounts because `react-apollo` gives me a hard time with unnecessary refetches.

I'm adding all the deleted comment ids to `deletedCommentsQueue` and when the `Comments` component unmounts i want to updated my global state but when the component about to unmount `deletedCommentsQueue` changes to an empty array even though we can see all the comment ids before we try to do our update.

I've made a simple [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zz0k6kn41) for you guys.

And this is my code for anyone who's interested

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const UserContext = createContext();

const comments = [
  { _id: 1, body: "first" },
  { _id: 2, body: "second" },
  { _id: 3, body: "third" }
];

const Comments = ({ commentIds }) => {
  const [deletedCommentsQueue, setDeletedCommentsQueue] = useState([]);

  const addToQueue = commentId => {
    setDeletedCommentsQueue([...deletedCommentsQueue, commentId]);
  };

  const { loggedUser, setLoggedUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      console.log("cleaning");
      console.log("deletedCommentsQueue", deletedCommentsQueue);

      const updatedComments = loggedUser.comments.filter(
        commentId => !deletedCommentsQueue.includes(commentId)
      );

      console.log(updatedComments);

      setLoggedUser({
        ...loggedUser,
        comments: updatedComments,
        likes: {
          ...loggedUser.likes,
          comments: loggedUser.likes.comments.filter(
            commentId => !deletedCommentsQueue.includes(commentId)
          )
        }
      });
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {deletedCommentsQueue.length > 0 && (
        <h1>Comment ids for deletion {deletedCommentsQueue.join(" ")}</h1>
      )}
      {commentIds.map(commentId => (
        <Comment
          deleted={deletedCommentsQueue.includes(commentId)}
          key={commentId}
          comment={comments.find(c => c._id === commentId)}
          deleteCommentFromCache={() => addToQueue(commentId)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Comment = ({ comment, deleted, deleteCommentFromCache }) => (
  <div>
    {deleted && <h2>Deleted</h2>}
    <p>{comment.body}</p>
    <button disabled={deleted} onClick={deleteCommentFromCache}>
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState({
    username: "asafaviv",
    comments: [1, 2, 3],
    likes: {
      comments: [1, 2]
    }
  });

  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ loggedUser, setLoggedUser }}>
        {mounted && <Comments commentIds={loggedUser.comments} />}
      </UserContext.Provider>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setMounted(!mounted)}>
        {mounted ? "Unmount" : "Mount"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of the empty dependency (`[]`) of the effect that you declare. That way, the effect is run once when the component is mounted.

Therefore, I guess in the context of its closure, `deletedCommentQueues` has the value of when the component was first mounted => `[]`.

I tried your codesandbox and if you remove that `[]` (which means the effect is called on each update), you get the correct value when you unmount the component but...the function is called on each update which does not solve your caching problem.

IMHO, I would suggest that you set your state (`const [deletedCommentsQueue, setDeletedCommentsQueue] = useState([]);`) in the parent component and save wherever you want the data as soon as the `mounted` value turns to `false` instead of watching from inside the component.